# bal build/pull throws "package not found: ballerinax/prometheus"

Tags: wso2, ballerina-swan-lake

Team,

Is there a way to fetch debug logs of the commands executed through bal tool.
Ex: bal build (or) bal pull .

I am getting package not found error when I execute above commands even though I am able to fetch the same package from another machine with the same commands. Sample command and output:

bal pull ballerinax/prometheus
"package not found: ballerinax/prometheus"
Ballerina version:
Ballerina 2201.8.2 (Swan Lake Update 8)
Language specification 2023R1
Update Tool 1.4.1

Expecting a debug command to debug the actions performed from the bal tool, to debug the package not found errors.